# Guitar Amplifier cause TV to flicker

Tags: amplifiers, noise, amplification

I have an interesting problem.

I have a Marshall MG30-DFX which is placed just behind my LCD TV (Samsung V32F390 if it matters). When I switch on or off my amp, the tv screen flickers.

I was wondering what is causing such behaviour?

Can the TV affect the sound quality of the amp?

Thanks

Comment: By behind you mean it is directly blocked by the TV? Why did you put it there?

Comment: It is half blocked I would say. The amp is high up in a shelf and the TV is on a shelf next to it blocking half of the amp. Limited space...

Comment: The tv will only affect the amp's sound by being in the way, not electrically or electronically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummmm yeah, well, where to start...
First, why would you place your amp behind a television? That alone sounds strange. Second, that amp has a 10" speaker with a very big magnet, and when all is powered up, that magnet will cause the television to flicker.

For more effects of magnetic power, leave your Rolex on top of the amp for a couple hours while powered up...

And yes, placing your amp behind anything will cause it to sound muffled and your playing will not sound clear. Pull that puppy out in the open.

Comment: Don't understand why the magnet on the speaker will have any different effect whether the amp is powered up or not. It's still a magnet, not an electro-magnet. Agree that it's not a good place for the amp, or a magnet, as magnets can cause some Gaussing effect , certainly on CRT tvs.